# How to call the Parent Dialog in Microsoft Teams Bot - NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, botframework, chatbot, teams-toolkit

I have three dialogs : `DialogA` , `DialogB` and `DialogC`.`DialogA` and `DialogB` can both call `DialogC`.Now if `DialogC` is called from `DialogA`, at the end of `DialogC`, how do I determine that the `DialogC` was called from `DialogA` and I need to call it back.
If I use `return await context.endDialog();` , it moves to the next step of the `DialogA`.
The dialog calls happen based on condition like

```
DialogA {
    async step1(context) {
        if(some condition) {
            return await context.beginDialog(DialogC);
        }
        //some other code
    }
    async step2(context) {
        //step2 processing code
    }
}
```

All the dialogs are **WATERFALLDIALOG**.So what I need to find is how do I return to the same point where I had called the `DialogC` from either of the dialogs `DialogA` or `DialogB` or restart the `DialogA` or `DialogB`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the ReplaceDialog class is possibly what you are looking for if I’ve understood your requirement. Also, you can pass in a value into your dialog using the options property too.

```
DialogA
var options = ‘FromDialogA’
return await context.beginDialog(DialogC, options)

DialogC
if (context.options == ‘FromDialogA’) {
// back to the parent dialog
return await context.replaceDialog(DialogA)
}
```

Comment: Actually I have used `context.replaceDialog()` but what I was missing was `context.next()` for one of the waterfall steps. Thanks for the help though.